# How can I remove "^@" char from a file?

Tags: shell, replace

I am trying to redirect the output of a isql (Sybase) and the file return strange characters at the end of the line `^@`. I need to delete this char for the full file. I can't use the output redirection inside the query because the BBDD I have doesn't have implemented this functionality.

example:

```
Node:SNMP_ALU_FTTH:INACT:Rack_1_SubRack_1_Slot_5_PON_4_ONT_34^@;Network Fail^@;1487336303;
```

This only happens if I redirect to a file:

```
./script.pl > result.txt
```

system info:

Linux XXXXXXX 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:39 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I've tried do a "dos2unix" over the file but nothing changed

Comment: What is a "BBDD"?

Comment: `^@` is a common way to display the null character.

Comment: How are you viewing the file?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Data Base in spanish :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, this symbol is the representation of the null character which is actually a non-printing character.

If you echo a null separated string or if you cat a null separated file you should see nothing.

To answer your question, you can remove null characters by using tr utility.

For example using `tr '\0' '\n' <file` (or `<<<"$var"`) will transliterate null characters to new lines.
Similarly `tr '\0' ' '` will convert null chars to spaces, etc.

Or you can use `tr -d '\0'` to delete null characters.

Remark:
Before to start playing around with the null character present in your string, be sure that you know what you are doing...  Notice that a lot of programs are capable to handle null character as input fields separator and some other programs may actually require data to be null separated. Also your program that generate this null separated string maybe can be adjusted to provide data based on a different separarator. Read the manuals.

Remark 2:
Just for the record, null chars can also be removed with sed: `sed 's/\x00/ /g' file`
This will also convert null character (hex code 00 = \x00) to space.
Sed can be combined with -i switch to apply changes in-place.

Comment: You solve my prob! Really thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are doing in the script. but with the help of below command you can remove the "^@" from the file.

```
sed -i -e "s/\^\@//g" result.txt
```

Comment: It's not likely that the file contains a literal `"^@"` sequence.

Comment: exactly, this command doesn't work because is not a literal char, it is a special separator (null char)